# Magento import a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: magento-1.9, database, import

I am trying to import(with bigdump) my live database to an test database. While importing the tables to the test database im getting the following error.

`MySQL: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (DB_Name.catalog_product_entity, CONSTRAINT FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ATTR_SET_ID_EAV_ATTR_SET_ATTR_SET_ID FOREIGN KEY (attribute_set_id) REFERENCES eav_attribute_set (attribute_set_id) ON )`

I have set the SET `Foreign_Key_Checks` but it seems this isn't changing the error at all.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
//Code
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Do I need to change table names? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I ended importing my MySQL database dump using SSH.

This could be done like this:

1. Upload the SQL file to the server.
2. If the database does not exist please create one with an user. Note the username and password.
3. Log into the server through SSH
4. Navigate to the directory where your .sql file is.
5. Type this this command: 
   mysql -uUSERNAME -p DATABASE_NAME < data.sql

This works for me and it is also much faster.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. You are talking about SSH but i never used it before, do i need to install some program or call my provider?

Comment: I use PuTTY as my SSH Client.

Comment: Aha found it! I am going to try it right now :)

Comment: New error has occured: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Did you ever have this error?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run) will help you.

Comment: Hmm, i think i need to contact my provider strato haha

Comment: Do i need to make a empty database or can i overwrite my new magento database ?

Comment: knospe you are an hero! I did it! i tried so many things and this made my day man haha. Thanks!!

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)